# Facebook wall post does not show thumbnail with Graph api, Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, facebook

I've tried to post image link from a current user photo album that the user had just uploaded to current user's friend wall by passing the image url.

```
NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                               @"http://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=106931612766138",@"link",
                               @"http://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=106931612766138",@"message",
                               nil];
[facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"User_Friend_ID/feed" andParams:params andHttpMethod:@"POST" andDelegate:self];
```

And the result showed below:

[Click to see the image](http://www.flickr.com/photos/76100405@N05/6836023603/)

But that not what I wanted.

When I try to paste the link inside the my friend's wall on facebook.com, facebook know and it's include a very nice thumbnail as the image:

[Click to see the image](http://www.flickr.com/photos/76100405@N05/6836023593/)

Can someone tell me what wrong with my code? or facebook dose not allow third party app to get this awesome feature?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem creating a wall post with a link to a 'just uploaded' YouTube video.  My solution was to introduce a 20 minute delay between uploading the video and creating the wall post.

Instead of the LINK parameter have you tried the PICTURE parameter instead?